How can I read/inject environment variables out of Kubernetes from Spring-Boot at runtime?
My program should test internal applications which are using Basic Authentication and OAuth2 and call them with different REST Calls.
First the user enters the address of the deployed application, the wanted REST Method(s) and also the credentials for either Basic Auth or OAuth2. And since the user should be able to re-use the input later I store these values in a database.
Since the credentials for Basic Auth or OAuth2 are already stored inside Kubernetes I thought it would be way easier and safer to just get the secrets from Kubernetes directly when the user hands over the name to which the secrets belong inside Kubernetes than to store them again in my database only to encrypt and decrypt them myself later on in the process.
I found a Github Documentation that uses the Kubernetes Java Client API to get data from Kubernetes but I think in my usecase that would be overkill... (the overkill I was talking about)
Is there a better way to read/inject Kubernetes environment variables from Spring-Boot? Or is there a different approach that I totally missed out on?

How many secrets do you have? Is that a fixed set or can that change?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Thomas Its two secrets and it's is a fixed set!

As you have only two secrets and they are static there is no need to integrate the Kubernetes API into your application.
You can mount the secrets to the filesystem and let your application consume the data or provide the content as environment variables and map them to Spring @ConfigurationProperties.
Spring provides also a module with built-in support to consume configmaps and secrets in case you want to use the Kubernetes API but don't want to implement it yourself.
